# System cooling policy option is missing

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I just bought a new Laptop (Sony SVT1311). The fan is always running and I would like to change some options to make it quieter.

I know that Windows 7 has an option System cooling policy but I can't find it on Windows.
Is there any way to active it, or some software/update to install?
Is it only for Windows 7 Professional?

As you can see in the next picture, I only have two options, minimal and maximal cpu charge.
[image]

Any other ideas how to reduce fan speed?

Answer (score 0):

You need the manufacturer-specific ACPI driver. Sometimes installing the [Intel chipset support](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20775&lang=eng&OSVersion=%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09&DownloadType=) is enough, but in your case you probably need the [Firmware extension](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=SVT13116FXS&upd_id=7510&os_group_id=6) (which performs ACPI management on Sony) and the [power management](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=SVT13116FXS&upd_id=7842&os_group_id=24). Note that for Windows 7 the power management is included in the [hotkey utilities](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=SVT13116FXS&upd_id=7633&os_group_id=6) for whatever reason.

If you have no missing drivers, then Sony utilities are probably actively disabling that feature. You have to uninstall the software suites, then reinstall only the drivers manually, either through Windows Update if available, or by extracting them from the above installers.

Comment: It didn't work :( I still have only 2 options in Processor Management...

Comment: Is it possible that the Motherbaord does not accept that users could change fan speed?